# Skipper- S3 file upload is not working in windows

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js

I'm using the =>

node 4.2.6
sailsjs 0.12.1

Frontend code =>

```
    function uploadFile(file, url, callback){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('image', file);
           $http.post(CONSTANTS.API_URL+url, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })
            .then(function (response) {
                callback(response);
            }, function (response) {
                callback(response);
            });
        }
```

backend :

```
        fileUploader(req, 'image', function(err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err || (!(uploadedFiles[0]))) {
                return res.json(400, err);
            } else {
                var url = uploadedFiles[0].extra.Location;
                if (url) {
                    sails.models.person.update(personId, { 'avtar': url },
                        function(err, updatedUrl) {
                            if (err || !updatedUrl) {
                                return res.json(500, { 'message': 'Unable to upload the Profile Pic' })
                            } else {
                                return res.ok({ profilePicUrl: url });
                            }
                        })
                }else{
                    return res.json(500, { 'message': 'Unable to upload the Profile Pic!' })
                }
            };
        });
```

I'm trying to upload the image in AWS S3 using skipper-s3. It is working fine in MAC OS X (10.11.4)

But when I'm trying to upload the image from the windows I'm getting the error :

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myProject\ .tmp\s3-upload-part-queue\mpu-\mylib\d9c7a41c-3407-4891-9ce4-b42c32d6feb2.jpg-6736-1463035484420-1']
>   I think this is something with the directory system.

Is it a skipper-s3 bug or I'm doing something wrong?